# How can I find different elements between two columns (generated by two subqueries)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, union

My subqueries produce a result like this:

```
coulmn1    column2
a          d
b          z1000
c          c
d
1
2
z1000      k
```

I want to know the different elements in both sets. column1 ={ a,b,c, 1,2,d, z1000,.....} column 2 ={ d,c,z1000,k......} The result I want is ={ a,k,1,2,....} hope I made it clear ..please let me know how could I do that..?

Comment: Where do "1" and "2" come from?

Comment: oops I forgot to add that in the diagram.  good observation Gordon.tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is full outer join:

```
select coalesce(t1.col1, t2.col2)
from t t1 full join
     t t2
     on t1.col1 = t2.col2
where t1.col1 is null or t2.col2 is null;
```

Another method doesn't require running the subquery twice;

```
select v.col
from t cross apply
     (values (t.col1, 1), (t.col2, 2)) v(col, which)
group by v.col
having min(v.which) = max(v.which);
```

Comment: @sunny . . . I'm rather surprised that you accepted a much more complicated answer posted significantly after this one.  However, the OP has the option of accepting whichever answer s/he thinks most appropriate.

Comment: nah I accepted both of them Gordon( in fact yours first). I am not sure how it got unticked...

Comment: yah got it now.. one answer

Answer (score 0):

```
--Test Data
with temp_table as (
    select 'a' coulmn1,'b' column2 union all
    select 'b' coulmn1,'z1000' column2 union all
    select 'c' coulmn1,'c' column2 union all
    select 'd' coulmn1,'' column2 union all
    select 'z1000' coulmn1,'k' column2 
)

--use cross join and union to distinct data 
--you have to change temp_table to your own table
select * into #temp_table from  (
    select T.coulmn1,T2.column2 as column2  
    from temp_table T,temp_table T2
    where T.coulmn1 <> T2.column2
) T;
select coulmn1 from #temp_table
union
select column2 from #temp_table;
```

[image]

[Test Link](http://rextester.com/CDUC16362)

Answer (score 0):

Use **EXCEPT** for this.

```
    SELECT column1
    FROM your_subquery
    EXCEPT
    SELECT column2
    FROM your_subquery
    UNION
    SELECT column2
    FROM your_subquery
    EXCEPT
    SELECT column1
    FROM your_subquery
```